# nodemon install error "No valid versions available for timed-out"

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I am getting this error when trying to install nodemon in a brand new node project.

I've created a blank folder named my-project
then, inside it, I've executed to creeate a package.json file:

```
 npm init -f
```

then when tryed to run

```
npm install --save-dev nodemon
```

And that was the result:

```
 npm ERR! code ENOVERSIONS
 npm ERR! No valid versions available for timed-out
```

I've just update my node version to the latest one and so npm tools.

```
node --version -> v8.9.4
npm --version -> 5.6.0
```

The funny part is that I've done this same steps in another computer 2 days ago with no problem.

```
325 verbose stack timed-out: No valid versions available for timed-out
325 verbose stack     at pickManifest (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\npm-pick-manifest\index.js:20:11)
325 verbose stack     at fetchPackument.then.packument (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\manifest.js:39:14)
325 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
325 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
325 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
325 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
325 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
325 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
325 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
325 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
325 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
325 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
325 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5)
326 verbose cwd E:\githubprojects\my-project\server
327 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
328 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save-dev" "nodemon@v1.14.7"
329 verbose node v8.9.4
330 verbose npm  v5.6.0
331 error code ENOVERSIONS
332 error No valid versions available for timed-out
333 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Official issue: https://github.com/npm/registry/issues/255

Official status: https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/41zfb8qpvrdj

> Several packages including "require-from-string" are currently unavailable. We are aware of the issue and are working to restore the affected user and packages. Please do not attempt to republish packages, as this will hinder our progress in restoring them.

**Update from NPM:**

> Resolved
>
> We apologize for the temporary unavailability of some packages. We will be publishing a comprehensive post-mortem update in the next few days.
>
> Posted Jan 06, 2018 - 23:14 UTC

Answer (score 2):

timed-out is a npm package that is apparently missing, as of the last day, or hour, or minutes (I don't know the time span).

/Users/Stan ==> npm install timed-out -g

```
npm ERR! code ENOVERSIONS
npm ERR! No valid versions available for timed-out

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Stan/.npm/_logs/2018-01-06T20_26_40_854Z-debug.log
```

Now it is working.

/Users/Stan ==> npm install timed-out -g

```
+ timed-out@4.0.1
added 1 package in 1.306s
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not you, it's an already known issue, due to dependency problems.

More details here https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1210

Answer (score 1):

Users are reporting that packages are being made available again. Try again and see if your issue is resolved.

https://github.com/npm/registry/issues/255