# ERROR npm install No valid versions available for https-proxy-agent-snyk-fork

Tags: node.js, npm, build, npm-install, snyk

Running the npm install for deploying purpose, I am getting the below error

```
+ npm install
npm ERR! code ENOVERSIONS
npm ERR! No valid versions available for https-proxy-agent-snyk-fork
```

The log file contains the below log

```
http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/https-proxy-agent-snyk-fork 1115ms
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for https-proxy-agent-snyk-fork@latest No valid versions available for https-proxy-agent-snyk-fork
9 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
10 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 2485ms
11 verbose type tag
12 verbose stack https-proxy-agent-snyk-fork: No valid versions available for https-proxy-agent-snyk-fork
```

Need some insight, it was working correctly a week ago and I didn't change the package.json as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nodemon install error "No valid versions available for timed-out"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48131550/nodemon-install-error-no-valid-versions-available-for-timed-out)

Comment: @SachinYadav I tried that solution but that didn't work for me, i am still getting the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the directory for https-proxy-agent-snyk-fork 
using

```
npm ls https-proxy-agent-snyk-fork
```

and found

```
`-- snyk@1.234.2
  `-- proxy-agent@3.1.0
    +-- https-proxy-agent-snyk-fork@2.2.2-fixed-mitm-vuln  (git://github.com/snyk/node-https-proxy-agent.git#5e86ccb682d0c833c8daa25ee6f91c670161cd66)
    `-- pac-proxy-agent@3.0.0 (git://github.com/snyk/node-pac-proxy-agent.git#e962ea0fe8db650a55e349e1b422e3ac99bfe451)
      `-- https-proxy-agent-snyk-fork@2.2.2-fixed-mitm-vuln  deduped (git://github.com/snyk/node-https-proxy-agent.git#5e86ccb682d0c833c8daa25ee6f91c670161cd66)
```

I updated the version for the root which is snyk here and 
I also updated my docker script for deployment from

```
npm install
```

to

```
npm install --global copy
npm install
```

Which solved the issue for me.